# Removing a user from all Drive access without deleting them

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

Using the [python drive api](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/index.html), I am attempting to remove any permissions a user has to a drive, folder, or file given their email. However, to do this it seems as though I must query all drives, then all files from all drives, then all permissions from all files. Only then can I comb every file permission to see if the id of the user on the permission matches the id of the user I want to remove permissions from. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you only want to deal with the files owned by a user, but to find all the objects that a user has permissions to access, that's not an easy thing to do: presumably you want specific writer/editor permissions, not "anyone in the organisation can edit" permissions. In our GSuite domain there are tens of millions of Drive files so this is an infeasible task.

A workaround for you is to move the user into an OU that does not have the Drive App enabled.  That removes all drive access for the user, though it's not really what you asked for.